# Converting html_text to dataframe in R

Tags: r

Looking to scrape a website to track information on paint and their prices:

```
bun <- read_html("https://www.bunnings.com.au/search/products?q=paint&sort=BoostOrder&page=1/")
bunhtml <- html_nodes(bun, "a")
buntest <- html_text(bunhtml)
```

How would I extract the html_text into a dataframe to look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really familiar with `rvest`, but this may get you start. I use `SelectorGadget` to find the notes. You may want to add more notes here.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

bun <- read_html("https://www.bunnings.com.au/search/products?q=paint&sort=BoostOrder&page=1/")
data.frame(  
  paint = bun %>% html_nodes(".product-title") %>% html_text(), 
  price = bun %>% html_nodes(".price-medium-size p") %>% html_text()
)
#>                                                                   paint   price
#> 1                                             Dulux Ceiling White Paint  $30.80
#> 2               Dulux 4L Interior Paint Wash&Wear Low Sheen Vivid White  $82.40
#> 3  British Paints Clean And Protect Low Sheen White Interior Paint - 4L  $63.90
#> 4            Taubmans Easycoat Low Sheen White Interior Wall Paint - 1L  $32.65
#> 5             Taubmans Endure Low Sheen White Interior Wall Paint - 10L    $172
#> 6                                   Spring 4L Flat White Interior Paint  $16.50
#> 7                                    Spring 4L Low Sheen Interior Paint     $24
#> 8            Taubmans 15L Trade Pro White Low Sheen Interior Wall Paint $102.50
#> 9                                   Dulux Design Black Chalkboard Paint     $48
#> 10                                       Dulux Design Gold Effect Paint    $144
#> 11                                      Dulux Design Pearl Effect Paint  $87.40
#> 12                                  Dulux 1L Design Theatre Black Paint  $36.90
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>